# Oracle Optimizer issue with UNION ALL

Tags: sql, oracle, union-all, optimization

I'm pretty confused by this behavior from Oracle optimizer. This has to do with union all operations from a CTE. If anyone has any ideas I'm all game.

```
 --Relevant data structures:
 --t_positionperf (index: POSITIONPERF_X1 (account_id, hist_date, security_id)
 --t_positionhist (index: POSITIONHIST_X1 (position_id, hist_date, hist_type)
 --                       PK_T_POSITIONHIST (hist_date, position_id, hist_type)
 --v_positiontype (very simple "case-when" translation of a tiny lookup table)

with q as (
select 
pp.position_id, pp.hist_date, pp.account_id, pp.income, pp.expense,
ph.position_type_id, ph.price, ph.quantity, ph.factor, ph.daily_accrual,
n.daily_accrual as new_daily_accrual, nvl(n.is_loan, v.is_loan) as new_is_loan
from
t_positionperf pp
left outer join t_positionhist ph
            on  pp.position_id = ph.position_id
            and pp.hist_date = ph.hist_date
            and ph.hist_type = 'O' --the 'O' join set from t_positionhist
     left outer join v_positiontype v 
                 on  ph.position_type_id = v.position_type_id
     left outer join (
                      select 
                      x.position_id, x.hist_date, x.daily_accrual, v2.is_loan 
                      from t_positionhist x 
                      join v_positiontype v2 on x.position_type_id = v2.position_type_id
                      where x.hist_type = 'N'
                     ) n --the 'N' join set from t_positionhist
                on  ph.position_id = n.position_id 
                and ph.hist_date = n.hist_date
where pp.account_id in (5018,5312)
and pp.hist_date between to_date('01-jan-14') and  to_date('31-jan-14')
)
select 
q.account_id,q.hist_date,q.position_id,q.income,
q.expense,q.position_type_id,q.price,q.quantity,q.factor
from q
```

This uses a sensible access path.

```
Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
         29  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
      37640  consistent gets
       5115  physical reads
          0  redo size
     227442  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
       4952  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
        409  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
       6116  rows processed


Execution Plan:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                        | Name              | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)  | Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                 |                   |   941 | 88454 |    5283   (1)| 00:01:04 |
|*  1 |  FILTER                          |                   |       |       |              |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS OUTER             |                   |   941 | 88454 |    5283   (1)| 00:01:04 |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER         |                   |   941 | 71516 |    2456   (1)| 00:00:30 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL            | T_POSITIONTYPE    |    64 |  1216 |       3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |     NESTED LOOPS OUTER           |                   |   941 | 53637 |    2452   (1)| 00:00:30 |
|   6 |      INLIST ITERATOR             |                   |       |       |              |          |
|   7 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T_POSITIONPERF    |   941 | 22584 |     567   (1)| 00:00:07 |
|*  8 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN          | POSITIONPERF_X1   |   941 |       |       6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | T_POSITIONHIST    |     1 |    33 |       2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 10 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | POSITIONHIST_X1   |     1 |       |       1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  11 |    VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE         |                   |     1 |    18 |       3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  12 |     NESTED LOOPS                 |                   |     1 |    27 |       4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  13 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | T_POSITIONHIST    |     1 |    20 |       3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 14 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | POSITIONHIST_X1   |     1 |       |       2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  15 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | T_POSITIONTYPE    |     1 |     7 |       1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 16 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | PK_T_POSITIONTYPE |     1 |       |       0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, if you add a UNION ALL to this select from the CTE, so that that the query looks like:

```
with q as (...) 
select q.account_id, q... etc.
UNION ALL
select q.account_id, max(q...) etc.
group by q.account_id
```

The Optimizer now wants to materialize the CTE (TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION). This part makes sense to me because of the UNION ALL from the same CTE. What I *don't* understand is why materializing the CTE causes it to choose a different (and much inferior) access path. It seems to lose the ability to push the predicate to the T_POSITIONHIST table when building the 'N' join set. You can see that it now does a Full Table Scan on T_POSITIONHIST, and as a result the disk I/O has gone **through the roof**:

```
Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
        362  recursive calls
         53  db block gets
     546116  consistent gets
     521527  physical reads
        688  redo size
     250541  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
       4952  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
        409  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
       6117  rows processed


Execution Plan
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                          | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                   |                             |  1882 |   205K|    13  (54)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION         |                             |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   LOAD AS SELECT                   | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6CB3_54C7EBF8 |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    FILTER                          |                             |       |       |            |          |
|*  4 |     HASH JOIN OUTER                |                             |   941 | 81867 |   147K  (3)| 00:29:32 |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER         |                             |   941 | 63047 |  2456   (1)| 00:00:30 |
|   6 |       VIEW                         | V_POSITIONTYPE              |    64 |   448 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL           | T_POSITIONTYPE              |    64 |   448 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |       NESTED LOOPS OUTER           |                             |   941 | 56460 |  2452   (1)| 00:00:30 |
|   9 |        INLIST ITERATOR             |                             |       |       |            |          |
|  10 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T_POSITIONPERF              |   941 | 22584 |   567   (1)| 00:00:07 |
|* 11 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN          | POSITIONPERF_X1             |   941 |       |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  12 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | T_POSITIONHIST              |     1 |    36 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 13 |         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | POSITIONHIST_X1             |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  14 |      VIEW                          |                             |  2358K|    44M|   145K  (3)| 00:29:02 |
|  15 |       VIEW                         |                             |  2358K|    51M|   145K  (3)| 00:29:02 |
|* 16 |        HASH JOIN                   |                             |  2358K|    67M|   145K  (3)| 00:29:02 |
|  17 |         VIEW                       | V_POSITIONTYPE              |    64 |   448 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  18 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL         | T_POSITIONTYPE              |    64 |   448 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 19 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL          | T_POSITIONHIST              |  2358K|    51M|   145K  (3)| 00:29:01 |
|  20 |   UNION-ALL                        |                             |       |       |            |          |
|  21 |    VIEW                            |                             |   941 |   106K|     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  22 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL              | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6CB3_54C7EBF8 |   941 | 56460 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  23 |    HASH GROUP BY                   |                             |   941 |    99K|     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|  24 |     VIEW                           |                             |   941 |    99K|     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  25 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL             | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6CB3_54C7EBF8 |   941 | 56460 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The weird part is, you can partially get around this issue by *duplicating* the CTE, like so:

```
with q as (...), q2 as (.../*duplicate of q*/)
select q.account_id, q... etc.
UNION ALL
select q2account_id, max(q2...) etc.
group by q2.account_id
```

Because it no longer wants to materialize the result set, it's able to use the smarter access path, except it has to do it twice, so the cost is approximately doubled (but still far less than the really bad access path it uses above).

### Statistics

```
     57  recursive calls
      0  db block gets
  73855  consistent gets
      0  physical reads
      0  redo size
 202937  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
   4953  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
    409  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
      0  sorts (memory)
      0  sorts (disk)
   6117  rows processed
```

Comment: What version?  Have you contacted Oracle support? Have you tried any hints? The optimizer is not perfect.

Comment: As said above optimizer is not perfect. The workaround I would suggest is to use a hint `with q as (select /*+INLINE*/ ...`. It has helped me in similar case.

Comment: It's 11g R2. I haven't contacted Oracle support yet but I think that's a good option. I'm just boggled by the fact that duplicating the CTE causes better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So eventually I discovered the answer: apparently the optimizer's decision to materialize a CTE ('With' block) will break the optimizer's ability to perform **Cost-Based Query Transformation** which in turn breaks the ability to perform certain operations like Join Predicate Pushdown (which is the *View Pushed Predicate* in the Explain Plan seen above) and Complex View Merge (a method of re-writing query blocks). Which might cause the optimizer to do horrible things like unnecessary full table scans on massive tables when you were expecting it to use some indexed access from the predicates attached to the query.

I ran into the problem in a couple of other situations and eventually ran into the following enlightening blogpost when doing research:
http://oracle-randolf.blogspot.com/2008/01/subquery-factoring-and-cost-based-query.html

It appears that originally any use of CTE disabled CBQT, but in 11.2.0.3 the optimizer will use CBQT if WITH views are inlined (i.e. NOT materialized), so now the problem is only visible if WITH view is chosen to be materialized. See comment from the link:
***Timur Akhmadeev*** said... 
just want to note that the issue no longer exists in 11.2.0.3. It is tracked under "allow CBQT if all WITH views are inlined" (11740670)

The two strategies seen here are both explained by this: (1) duplicating the WITH view and (2) Yaroslav Shabalin's suggestion to use the INLINE hint

Comment: I've been struggling with a similar problem and ended up fixing it with /*+ PUSH_PRED(viewalias) */ hint.  (I also updated 11.2.0.2 to 11.2.0.4).  Not sure if the version upgrade was necessary, but the hint IS necessary in my case.